# Use Office365 Rest API Oauth2 to access Calendars for multiple Organizations

Tags: php, rest, exchangewebservices, office365, azure-active-directory

We want to use Office365 Rest API and Oauth2 to access Calendars for multiple Organizations.

Rest and Oauth2... No problem.

Same organization...  No problem.

Different organization...  Big trouble!!!!

We want our web application to have an office365 login similar to the Facebook connect experience *for any office365 user in any organization* (Multi-tenancy).

Has anyone successfully done this?  Any language?

Is there something to configure in the app beyond selecting "Multiple Organizations"?

Note:  we are developing our application in PHP5+.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the walkthrough [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn759432(v=office.15).aspx) generates an ASP.NET C# app that reads calendar for multiple organizations. A user in any organization can login and display their calendar.

You didn't say what the trouble is. Are you getting a specific error?